# How to fix client browser caching issue while using IIS?

Tags: caching, browser, iis-8.5, clientcache

I have developed cloud application in ASP.NET. After every deployment, the portal either shows white screen or shows older version of the application.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I have already tried:
1) Updating JS version in each deployment (white screen issue was resolved by this)
2) Recycling Application Pool 
3) IIS manager->http response header->set common headers->enable web content
4) Restarting IIS(8.5) after each deployment

However, none of these have worked. The application works fine in incognito mode of Chrome browser but not the regular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, none of these have worked. The application works fine in incognito mode of Chrome browser but not the regular one.

As far as I know, if your brower has accessed your web application once, it will store the cache in client side.

If you modify the content and add the response header, it will not re-send the request to the server, it will use the cache page.

To aovid this, the only way is clear the browser's cache or use Ctrl+F5 to refresh the page.

Then if your reponse haeder contains the no-cache next time, the browser will not store the cache again.

Comment: Thanks @Brando. But it will be difficult to ask all clients to clear the cache and most of them are non-IT guys, so would make it even harder. 

So any other solution to this?

Comment: Since you have return the cache header in the first response, that means the client browser will cache the page. It will not receive the new response header. In my opinion, the only way now is telling customer to use ctrl+F5 to refresh the page.